# getting object properties and values recursivly

Tags: php, object, foreach

so i have an object:

```
$user->name->first = "Bob";
$user->name->last = "Smith";
$user->address->street = "1234 anywhere st.";
$user->address->city = "Chicago";
$user->address->state = "Texas";
```

how can i iterate through this object without knowing the "name,address" property?

I want to be able to do

```
 foreach ($user as $key -> $value)
 {}
```

now i can do this:

```
 foreach ($user as $key -> $value)
 {
         foreach ($value as $k => $v)
         {
           echo $k . "," . $v . "\n";
         }
 }
```

and i get a nice little list of

```
 first,Bob
 last,Smith
 street,1234 anywhere st.
 city,Chicago
 state,Texas
```

but how can i get the property name or address to print?

i.e.

```
 name,first,Bob
 name,last,Smith
 address,street,1234 anywhere st.
 address,city,Chicago
 address,state,Texas
```

Comment: It's in `$key`...also, its `=>` not `->`

Comment: yep it sure is. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you want is in `$key` already from the first `foreach` loop.

```
foreach ($user as $key => $value)
{
    foreach ($value as $k => $v)
    {
        echo "$key,$k,$v\n";
    }
}
```

[IDEOne.com demo](http://ideone.com/DCqfkB)